# Telethon remove all sessions after start

Tags: python-3.x, python-asyncio, telegram, telethon

I run the script, it is start to parse messages, but after about a minute, it is cutting all the sessions, including my desktop and mobile.

I have a little script, which is just sending the request with new message data to my API.
All is working, when I use my Belarusian number or Georgian number. BUT everything goes wrong, when I use Russian phone. I'm not sure, if it is a real dependecy, maybe the problem is in some settings. But this script didn't work for 3 different Telegram accounts with russian's phones.
What is happening:
Does nybody know something about it?
(I delete session file, and using individual api_id and api_hash for each run)

```
from telethon.sync import TelegramClient
from telethon import events

async def get_participants_fullname(group):
    users = {}
    async for partic in client.iter_participants(group):
        lastname = partic.last_name if partic.last_name else ""
        users[partic.id] = f"{partic.first_name} {lastname}".strip()
    return users

async def process_message(event, group):
       participants = await get_participants_fullname(event.chat_id)
       # send the request with message data

with TelegramClient('session', api_id, api_hash) as client:
    async def get_groups():
        dialogs = await client.get_dialogs()
        groups = {dialog.id: dialog.title for dialog in dialogs if dialog.is_group}
        return groups


    @client.on(events.NewMessage(incoming=True))
    async def handle_new_message(event):
        await process_message(event, await get_groups())


    print('Listening for new messages...')
    client.run_until_disconnected()
```

Comment: You're likely affected by https://github.com/LonamiWebs/Telethon/issues/4051.